# Are there online examples on how to create a custom checkbox using ToggleableStateMixin?

Tags: flutter

Flutter Newbie. I wanted to create a custom checkbox using ToggleableStateMixin. I've been looking online for an example of how to use ToggleableStateMixin to do this but no luck. Any quick guidance or links that I could read on how to proceed would be extremely helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Share your code snippet

Comment: I'm ashamed to say there's no code snippet yet. I've been reading the docs for ToggleableStateMixin but I still have no idea on how to proceed  Would you be able to provide a quick guide on how you would do it if it were you?

Comment: you need to use `ToggleablePainter` - if still not sure on how to do that, check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/18116933e7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart#L343 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/18116933e7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart#L483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build your custom checkbox with ToggleableStateMixin:

```
 class customCheckbox extends State<StatefulWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin<StatefulWidget>, ToggleableStateMixin {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    
      @override
      // TODO: implement onChanged
      ValueChanged<bool?>? get onChanged => throw UnimplementedError();
    
      @override
      // TODO: implement tristate
      bool get tristate => throw UnimplementedError();
    
      @override
      // TODO: implement value
      bool? get value => throw UnimplementedError();
     
    }
```

also can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleableStateMixin-mixin.html